# How to reverse engineer JavaFX lambda expression and get class definition for EventHandler and ActionListener

Tags: javafx, lambda, event-handling, actionlistener, eventhandler

I'm doing my best to learn JavaFX, and although lambda expression are great, I sometimes need to write my code for handling events in separate classes the reuse similar logic. The majority of tutorials I've found use lambda expressions to create an anonymous inner class that handles the event.

Something like this which changes a label's text if the text inside a TextField changes

```
class1Grade.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    gpaOverallLabel.setText( class1Grade.getText() );
});
```

The problem is I have a bunch of pairs of labels and TextFields and want to write 1 class for handling all the same type of event and then just register this class with the TextFields since I can't really reuse the lambda expression.

I don't know what method or class this part is creating

```
(observable, oldValue, newValue)
```

I found [this page on JavaFX events](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-event-handlers-and-change-listeners/#textbox-events) very helpful and was able to add an event to the TextField any time to focus changes (i.e. user presses tab).

I started with this code

```
// Listen for TextField text changes
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
            String oldValue, String newValue) {

        outputTextArea.appendText("TextField Text Changed (newValue: " + newValue + ")\n");
    }
});
```

And was able to successfully make the lambda expression into a class that can be used for multiple TextFields

```
class TextFieldListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {
    private final TextField numericTextField;
    private final Label errorLabel;

    TextFieldListener(TextField numericTextField, Label errorLabel) {
        this.numericTextField = numericTextField;
        this.errorLabel = errorLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if(!newValue){  // check if focus gained or lost
            //check if INVALID
            String errorText = " err";
            // String errorText = model.getNumericErrorTextIfInvalid();
            errorLabel.setText(numericTextField.getText()+errorText);
        }
    }
}
```

And I can register this class with my TextFields in other parts of the code

```
class1Grade.focusedProperty().addListener(new TextFieldListener(class1Grade, class1GradeError));
class1Credits.focusedProperty().addListener(new TextFieldListener(class1Credits, class1CreditsError));
```

**My big questions is how do I take a lambda expression example and find out the actual underlying method or class related to event handling that it's calling?**

Comment: Just check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) for the method to which the lambda is being passed. Sometimes you have to do a little extra work: `StringProperty` has two `addListener` methods, but the signature of the lambda only matches one of the interfaces.

Comment: Of course you CAN reuse lambdas!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately in case of lambda expressions used as method parameters you need to consider all overloaded versions of the method that take a functional interface as parameter. In this case for `StringProperty.addListener` there are the following possibilities:

- `ChangeListener<? super String>`
- `InvalidationListener`

Now check, if the abstract methods of those interfaces have a suitable signature.

In this case `InvalidationListener.invalidated` takes only a single parameter eliminating it as possibility. `ChangeListener.changed` takes 3 parameters which means the signature is suitable...

However some IDEs should provide the functionality to do this work for you automatically. E.g. NetBeans 8 shows a light-bulb next to the line of code, if you place your cursor inside the lambda expression and clicking on it shows the option *Use anonymous inner class* which automatically converts the lambda expression to a anonymous inner class.